# How do you find the composition of three functions

Tags: euclidean-geometry, isometry

We have learned that if you let $P$ be the Euclidean plane with distance $d$, a function $F: P \to P$ is an isometry if, for all points $X$ and $Y$ of $P$, $d(F(X),F(Y)) = d(X,Y)$. Also the following types of transformations are isometries: translation, rotation, reflection, glide reflection. The identity transformation is the function $F$ defined by $F(X) = X$ for all $X$. In other words, for all points $X$ the transformed point $X'$ equals $X$. A translation with translation vector $0$ is the identity. A rotation with rotation angle $0$ is the identity.

My question is that if a translation of the reals is a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that there is a constant $b$ so that

$f(x)=x+b$

for all reals $x$ . The  reflection of the real line in a point $u$ is the function $f(x)$ such that $u$ is the midpoint of $x$ and $f(x)$ for all $x$.

How do you find the composition $h\circ g\circ f$ of three functions: a translation $f$ , a reflection $g$ , and a translation $h$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We write the translations $h,f$ as $h(x)=x+a$ and $f(x)=x+b$. We can also write $g$ as $g(x)=2u-x$, where $u$ is the unique stationary point of $g$. The composition is given by
$$(h\circ g\circ f)(x)=h(g(f(x)))=h(g(x+b))=h(2u-(x+b))=(2u-(x+b))+a$$
This is
$$2u-b+a-x=2\left(u-\frac{b-a}{2}\right)-x$$
which is a reflection in the point $u-\frac{b-a}{2}$

Comment: Okay that is making a little more sense, would it be similar for a reflection F , a translation G , and a reflection H?

Comment: @user253465 yes it will be similar. Because the functions take such simple forms, it's fairly simple to combine them and recognise the resulting form

Comment: would you  mind showing me how you would write the functions and how they create the composition? I have had no formula visual for this chapter and I am having a hard time understanding

Comment: Are you wanting to work in the reals or in the Euclidian Plane? The reals are much simpler, as there isn't really a concept of rotation that is distinct from reflection.

Comment: We are working in the reals.

Comment: for example we are working with the reals and it is similar to the last problem but it is A  translation of the reals is a function f:R→R such that there is a constant b so that 
f(x)=x+b 
for all reals x . The  reflection of the real line in a point u is the function f(x) such that u is the midpoint of x and f(x) for all x . 
 
What is the composition h∘g∘f of three functions: a reflection f , a translation g , and a reflection h ?

Comment: @user253465 we're going to apply the same approach as before. We have g(x)=x+c, f(x)=2a-x, h(x)=2b-x, where a and b are the stationary points of f and h respectively, and c is the amount we are translating by. So the composition is h(g(f(x)))=h(g(2a-x))=h(2a-x+c)=2b-(2a-x+c)=2(b-a+½ c)-x. So this is a reflection in the point b-a+½ c